# Launch another activity as soon as user clicks on the SearchView

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview

I know this is a common issue.

However, launching another activity whenever user clicks on the searchView (not the icon) is not working unless user submits the query.

Below are functional codes, that result whenever user submits a query, it launches another activity, however, I want to launch another activity as soon as user clicks on the searchView (expanded textfield).

Thanks in advance.

xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_page"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeMain">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchActivity" >
        </meta-data>

    </activity>

    <provider android:name=".MySuggestionProvider"
        android:authorities="ad.aureus.apicius.MySuggestionProvider" />

    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>

        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

    </activity>
```

MainPage.class

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_page, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class)));



    return true;
}
```

BTW, I have tried where you can write if/switch statements in onOptionsItemSelected method to identify the searchView id then use Intents. Both did not work.

onCreate method:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
                MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, MySuggestionProvider.MODE);
        suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null);
```

I do have this in onCreate, for the recent query suggestions, and I am not sure whether if this is the reason for my issue. I'm assuming that, because this is called initially, it suppresses the onOptionsItemSelected method's attributes? Not sure..

Here's a xml for menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/title_activity_main_page"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    />
```

Comment: Try using SearchView's on setOnQueryTextListener and inside this onQueryTextChange check that if the length isequal to 0 then Shift to another activity try this and let me know

Comment: put a listener to your View

Comment: so you want to start another activity, when user just clicks a SearchView, **not typing** any text inside? why? what for?

Comment: Why don't you just use searchView.setOnClickListener();?

Comment: This is because I have different purposes for those two activities and mainly because the search widget is only for display until user clicks on it.

Comment: `SearchView`, as its name suggest, is for searching, not for clicking and starting a new activity, if you want such a thing use `Button`, `ImageButton`, `TextView`, whatever

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some of the alternative methods in implementing the if length is 0 start a new activity, and setting setOnClickListener they have worked but only when I clicked on the logo which did not work when I set the icon to false.

In consideration to pskink's comment, I took a different approach that had solved my issue. It was rather a really simple approach where I got rid of the SearchView and changed that to EditText field to allow instant onClick on a single tap to another activity.

Thank you very much for the alternative thoughts and solutions for the issue. They have been a great help as I will reference them later on and that I now know which works and those that don't.